# How to set center elements in body without centering all elements within main elements?

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

I'm trying to set text-align: center to the body to get my divs within to work properly, but this then centers all text everywhere in my page. How can I set text-align to the body so that it only affects the body and divs within but not everything within the divs?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="leftColumn"><!--stuff--></div>
<div class="centerColumn"><!--stuff--></div>
<div class="rightColumn"><!--stuff--></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.leftColumn, .centerColumn, .rightColumn {
    margin: 16px;
    border: 2px solid var(--medium) !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    margin-top: 98px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.leftColumn, rightColumn {
    width: 300px;
}

.centerColumn{
    min-width: 900px;
    margin: auto; /* This doesn't center the center column so I'm trying to use text-align to center this. */
}

.rightColumn {
    float: right;
    right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Elements inherit properties from their parents. In this case you would have to reset the `text-align` property on the columns otherwise since they would inherit the `text-align:center` property set on the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code:

```
.leftColumn, .centerColumn, .rightColumn {
    margin: 16px;
    border: 2px solid var(--medium) !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    margin-top: 98px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

solution:

```
.leftColumn, .centerColumn, .rightColumn {
    margin: 16px;
    border: 2px solid var(--medium) !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    margin-top: 98px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left; /* setting alignment inside */
}
```

plus:

```
body{
   text-align: center; /*  setting alignment outside */
}
```

Comment if it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
   text-align: center;
}
```

This will center the body in css code. Also, with specific things that you want to center, give it an id `<div id = "demo"></div>` and replace the body in the css with the id.